# Not able to send notifications from my facebook APP to other users

Tags: facebook, notifications

I created a FaceBook canvas application which is not a game application.
when I log in with my e-mail id in graph explorer, I am able to send post notification to my user id using graph API as given below:

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/notifications?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&template=MY_MESSAGE&href=fbWantsThisLink.html?butIDontNeedIt=123.

But when I try to send notifications to other user ids I am getting below exception:

> "Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
>   "type": "GraphMethodException",      "code": 100"

though other users have authorized my app.

Any pointers to resolve this?

Comment: Whose access token are you using? I assume it's that of the user you're trying to create the notification for, or that it's the app access token and you're sure they're authorised users of your app?

Comment: We are using applications access token (app ID|secret)and the users are authorized to use our application.Other than accepting login_dialog,is there anything else user needs to do to get authorized to with my app

Comment: Are you sure the user you're trying to create the notification for is an authorised user of the app and hasn't blocked the app or removed it from their profile? that's the most likely error here